# Chaining multiple instances of the same named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inner-join

I've got a Rails app with models called Item, ItemTag, and Tag. Items have many Tags through ItemTags. The associations are working correctly.

I want to build a search interface for Items that allows filtering by multiple Tags. I have a bunch of named scopes for various conditions, and they chain without problems. I figure I'll build the query based on user input.  So I made a scope that returns the set of Items that has a given tag:

```
scope :has_tag, -> (tag_id) { joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag_id}) }
```

It works!

```
>  Item.has_tag(73).count
=> 6

>  Item.has_tag(81).count
=> 5
```

But:

```
> Item.has_tag(73).has_tag(81).count
=> 0
```

There are two items that have both tags, but chaining the scopes together produces the following SQL, which is always going to return empty, for obvious reasons; it's looking for a tag that has two ids, rather than an item that has two tags.

```
SELECT [items].* 
FROM [items] 
INNER JOIN [item_tags] ON [item_tags].[item_id] = [items].[id] 
INNER JOIN [tags] ON [tags].[id] = [item_tags].[tag_id] 
WHERE [tags].[id] = 81 AND [tags].[id] = 73
```

I know I can get the intersection of the collections after they're returned, but this seems inefficient, so I'm wondering if there is a standard practice here. (It seems like a common task.)

```
>  (Item.has_tag(73) & Item.has_tag(81)).count
=> 2
```

Is there a way to write the scope to make this work, or will this need to be done another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the input tags need to be processed as an array, not chained. With this statement, you're getting a subset under tag(83) of tag(71), which is not what you want. The query confirms this.

```
Item.has_tag(73).has_tag(81).count
```

You might try a scope that processes the tags as an array and then constructs the query using lambda

```
 scope :has_tags, lambda { |tag_ids| includes(:tag_ids)
    .where("tag_id IN (?)", tag_ids.collect { |tag_id| } )
    .group('"items"."id"')
    .having('COUNT(DISTINCT "tag_ids"."id") = ?', tag_ids.count) }
```

I don't have full knowledge of your model relationship setups, etc, and I'm the typo queen, so the snippet above may or may not work out of the box, but I think the information here is that yes, you can process a set of tags in a single scope and query once to get a collection.

Comment: This pointed me in a useful direction. But it doesn't work as written. One problem is that I want to return all of the columns, like a normal ActiveRecord query would, and that means grouping by every column- not just items.id.  Also, tags_id.collect {|tag_id|} returns an array full of nils; using the array directly works fine.

Comment: I hate posting untested chunk of code for tat reason, but at least it was helpful. Good question, though. Thought-provoking.